# How do I Iterate through the whole array before callback on nodejs?

Tags: arrays, node.js, series, waterfall

I'm trying to iterate through the whole array before the callback. I'm beginner on nodejs and I'm still grasping how to use the concept of callback.

Bumped into async.eachSeries / mapSeries / waterfall and I'm trying different combinations but none work.

I'd like to ensure that the calls to the tasks on the waterfall array are executed for both arrays on eachSeries (myExchanges and signalso) before calling back.

```
async.eachSeries(myExchanges, function (exchange, outerCB){         
        async.eachSeries(signalso, function(signal,innerCB){                                
            let thisExchangeBuckets = Object.values(custCurrBalance).filter(bal=> bal.exchange===exchange.id)
            var tasko = [async.apply(sigo, signal,exchange, thisExchangeBuckets),availableBalancesC, availableSymbolsC, executeOrders]  
            const response =  async.waterfall(tasko, (err, results) => {
                thisOrders.push(results)                                
                var json = JSON.stringify(thisOrders,null,2);
                fs.writeFileSync(newBalFilePath,json);                  
            })
            innerCB(null);
        },
        function(err) 
        {
            outerCB(null);  // outer callback
        });
    },
    function(err) 
    {
        console.log('all done!!!');
    });
    processAllCB(thisOrders);
```

1. results at doAll undefined (this one comes from the called back function)
2. all done!!! (this one comes from the last code line provided above)
3. HERE Im getting the execution of the functions on waterfall

I expect

1. functions of waterfall
2. all done!!!
3. results at doAll [array of placed orders]

Comment: Do you need to call innerCB in the callback for waterfall instead of after initiating the waterfall?

Comment: Not sure I got your question. Are you suggesting that I make I place the innerCB inside the waterfall? If I do it the callback returns after executing the first order (first item in the array)